# "Access is denied" in IE 10/11

Tags: iis-6, .net-2.0, windows-server-2003, access-denied

I have a web site that works fine with Chrome and FF but chokes on IE 10 and 11.
I have googled the issue but can't find a solution that fixes this problem. I checked the serve event logs, IIS log, set compatibility mode on, nothinf fixes it. I keep getting:

"Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server. "

I checked IIS and it does allow script access, Keep Alive is checked, not using jQuery, ...

I am using form authentication (against AD) and have the following in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="Account/Login.aspx" timeout="15"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Any other ideas on how to tackle this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a one size fit solution but for my settings this worked:

I removed `<deny users="?">` and it works in IE. In IIS Directory Security, under Authentication and Access Control, I had enabled "Enable Anonymous Access", using a Windows user account and password (with access to AD). I needed that to authenticate users against AD using forms authentication. It might be a conflict (at least in IE's point of view) between  in web.config and "Enable Anonymous Access" in IIS.